Как заполнить поле плитками (спрайты) чтобы заполнить всё пространство?
Мне надо, чтобы поле игры (800 на 600) было заполнено спрайтами (48 на 48) без пропусков и та плитка, на которую наведена мышь имела белую окантовку. (не 2D майнкрафт!)
Код который я писал приведён ниже. (можете заменить наложение текстур на рисовку квадрата.)
Кста, о функции Render_texture, я делал свою библиотечку, не удивляйтесь.
Render_texture(текстура, X, Y, rect от пайгейм, название окна из(pygame.display.set_mode))
try:
    import pygame
except ImportError:
    import os
    os.system("pip install pygame")
    import pygame

import random
from Lib import Render_texture

pygame.init()

white = (254, 254, 254)   # цвета тут  --> COLORS <--
yellow = (253, 255, 102)
black = (1, 1, 1)
gray = (120, 120, 120)
dark = (100, 100, 100)
brown = (109, 100, 90)
red = (252, 39, 39)
green = (10, 180, 10)
lightblue = (80, 150, 255)
blue = (53, 125, 231)
orange = (255, 100, 130)

dis_width = 800
dis_height = 600

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
# тут было наложение иконки на окно.
pygame.display.set_caption('My game')

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

texture = pygame.image.load('Textures/EXPbattery_mine.png')
texture2 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Copper_block_mine.png')
texture4 = pygame.image.load('Textures/DirtTitle_mine.png')
texture5 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Iron_ore_mine.png')


block = 48
rect = pygame.Rect(48, 48, 48, 48)
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
background = pygame.sprite.Group()


def coll(spd, ore):
    if spd[0] > ore.X and spd[0] < ore.X + block and spd[1] > ore.Y and spd[1] < ore.Y + block:
        return 1


def rnd():
    stx8 = round(random.randrange(0 + block, dis_width - block * 2) / float(block)) * float(block)
    sty8 = round(random.randrange(0 + block, dis_height - block * 2) / float(block)) * float(block)
    return stx8, sty8


class background_tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = texture4.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(X + 24, Y + 24))
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y


class ore_deposit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = texture.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(X + 24, Y + 24))
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y


def gameloop():
    k234 = 0
    k235 = 0
    slist = []
    for u in range(0, 7):
        f, f2 = rnd()
        ores = ore_deposit(f, f2)
        slist.append(ores)
        blocks.add(ores)
    slist2 = []
    for u in range(0, 8):
        f = k234
        f2 = k235
        k234 += 48
        if k234 >= 816:
            k234 = 0
            k235 += 48
            if k235 >= 624:
                break
        oresg = background_tile(f, f2)
        slist2.append(oresg)
        background.add(oresg)
    game = True

    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():        # события и управление
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False

        dis.fill(gray)
        background.draw(dis)
        blocks.draw(dis)

        spd = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i in range(0, len(blocks)):
            if (coll(spd, slist[i])) == 1:
                Render_texture(texture2, (slist[i]).X, (slist[i]).Y, rect, dis)
        for j in range(0, len(background)):
            if (coll(spd, slist2[j])) == 1:
                Render_texture(texture5, (slist2[i]).X, (slist2[i]).Y, rect, dis)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(FPS)


gameloop()


Не знаю почему, но теперь заработало.
Вот код после проблемы (его я уже улучшил):
import sys

try:
    import pygame
except ImportError:
    import os
    os.system("pip install pygame")
    import pygame

import random
from IronForge import Render_texture

pygame.init()

white = (254, 254, 254)   # цвета тут  --> COLORS <--
yellow = (253, 255, 102)
black = (1, 1, 1)
gray = (120, 120, 120)
dark = (100, 100, 100)
brown = (109, 100, 90)
red = (252, 39, 39)
green = (10, 180, 10)
lightblue = (80, 150, 255)
blue = (53, 125, 231)
orange = (255, 100, 130)

dis_width = 800
dis_height = 600

dis = pygame.display.set_mode((dis_width, dis_height))
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("Textures/Logo.ico"))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mine game')

FPS = 60
k = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

sound_click_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/click/standart_ckick.mp3')
sound_click_2 = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound/click/dolgiy_click.mp3')

texture = pygame.image.load('Textures/EXPbattery_mine.png')
texture2 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Copper_block_mine.png')
texture3 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Copper_ore_mine.png')
texture4 = pygame.image.load('Textures/DirtTitle_mine.png')
texture5 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Iron_ore_mine.png')
texture6 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Leadmetall_mine.png')
texture7 = pygame.image.load('Textures/Minerr_mine.png')
texture_frame = pygame.image.load('Textures/Item_frame_mine.png')

block = 48
rect = pygame.Rect(48, 48, 48, 48)  # ore deposit
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()
background = pygame.sprite.Group()


def coll(spd, ore, sound=sound_click_2):
    global k
    if spd[0] > ore.X and spd[0] < ore.X + block and spd[1] > ore.Y and spd[1] < ore.Y + block:
        sop = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if sop[0] == True:
            if k != 1:
                sound.play()
                k = 1
        elif sop[0] == False:
            k = 0
        return 1


def rnd():
    stx8 = round(random.randrange(0 + block, dis_width - block * 2) / float(block)) * float(block)
    sty8 = round(random.randrange(0 + block, dis_height - block * 2) / float(block)) * float(block)
    return stx8, sty8


class background_tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = texture4.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(X + 24, Y + 24))
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y


class ore_deposit(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = texture.convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(X + 24, Y + 24))
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y


def gameloop():
    stop = False
    k234 = 0
    k235 = 0
    slist = []
    for u in range(0, 7):
        f, f2 = rnd()
        ores = ore_deposit(f, f2)
        slist.append(ores)
        blocks.add(ores)
    slist2 = []
    for u in range(0, 232):
        f = k234
        f2 = k235
        k234 += 48
        if k234 >= 816:
            k234 = 0
            k235 += 48
            if k235 >= 624:
                break
        oresg = background_tile(f, f2)
        slist2.append(oresg)
        background.add(oresg)
    game = True

    while game:
        while stop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():  # события и управление
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                        stop = False

        for event in pygame.event.get():        # события и управление
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    stop = True

        dis.fill(gray)
        background.draw(dis)
        blocks.draw(dis)

        spd = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i in range(0, len(blocks)):
            if (coll(spd, slist[i])) == 1:
                Render_texture(texture_frame, (slist[i]).X, (slist[i]).Y, rect, dis)
        for j in range(0, len(background)):
            if (coll(spd, slist2[j], sound_click_1)) == 1:
                Render_texture(texture_frame, (slist2[j]).X, (slist2[j]).Y, rect, dis)

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(FPS)


gameloop()

